# Generating sequences of random number iteratively

Tags: c++, random

I want to generate many sequences of random numbers in quick succession using C++. The problem I am facing is getting the same sequence using my code. Consider the following toy example of generating variates from U[0,1]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
// function to generate uniform random
// variates on [0,1]
void uniform(double *pt, int n);

int main()
{
    // File to output results
    ofstream output("output.txt");


    // Generate two sequences of uniform random variates
    double uniform_variates1[10];
    double *pt_uniform1 = uniform_variates1;
    uniform(pt_uniform1, 10);

    double uniform_variates2[10];
    double *pt_uniform2 = uniform_variates2;
    uniform(pt_uniform2, 10);

    // Output results
    for( int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        output << uniform_variates1[i] << "\t" << uniform_variates2[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void uniform(double *pt, int n)
{
    // seed for rand()
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    for( int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pt[i] = 1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX;
    }
}
```

A sample output of this code, indicative of all other runs is shown below.

```
0.0769677   0.0769677
0.933256    0.933256
0.234535    0.234535
0.413251    0.413251
0.0505387   0.0505387
0.854274    0.854274
0.0886563   0.0886563
0.57152 0.57152
0.697195    0.697195
0.7004  0.7004
```

As can be seen, these two sequences are absolutely identical. How can I avoid this problem? I need to do something similar for a project, except that I require about a 1000 unique random number sequences.

Comment: First, this isn't **C** code. Second, [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) Its whats for dinner; *seriously*. (and regarding your root problem, call `srand()` *once* at the startup of your process and *never again*).

Comment: Only call `srand()` once per program run. Tipically one of the first things `main()` does.

Comment: Apologies, I have made the correction.

Comment: Move that call to `srand()` to your `main()`, you only need to set the seed once.

Comment: Your problem is probably calling srand over and over again. Because time_t is number of *seconds*, your code probably runs fast enough that on each call to uniform, the PRNG is being seeded with the same value, leading too two identical series. I'm not sure about this, but it may be important.

Comment: Thank you for the swift replies; it is indeed as everyone suspects.

Comment: @Comp_Warrior assuming this is single-threaded, [see it live](http://ideone.com/E5zxmn) using `<random>` instead of legacy `rand()`. Seriously. the C++11 random lib is the cat's whiskers. Use it if you can.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for that illustration; I shall keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand how PRNG work, and the hint is in the P for **Pseudo** (the rest is Random Number Generator).

A PRNG does not create a random sequence of number because it is not random: for the same input (seed) the same sequence is always produced, and this sequence *cycles* at a given period. For example, the common [32 bits Mersenne Twiser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) has a period of 2<sup>19932</sup>-1 elements, meaning that it would cycle after that many iterations. Of course, there are other interesting properties, such as the speed of generation or the "randomness" observed, I advise you read the article.

What matters most, though, is that a PRNG is totally dependent on its seed; therefore as long as you give it the same seed, it will return the same sequence of numbers. In your case, the C library uses a single (hidden and unspecified) PRNG seeded by `srand` and iterating over its sequence via `rand`. The issue you observed is due to the lack of precision of the `time` function that you use to seed this PRNG: because it is only precise at the second, if you draw N series within the same second you will get all N identical. This can be solved by better seeding: **Only seed once, at the start of the process.**

*Note: some pocker servers using `time(0)` as a seed were hacked a few years ago, because the output of `time` is hardly a secret; for secrecy PRNG are not sufficiency, you need CSPRNG that is Cryptographically Secure PRNG.*

Now, there is also the issue that, unfortunately, using global state leaves a bad state in the mouth (concurrency issues and all...) and thus it is advisable to use the C++11 `<random>` library if you have access to it. In C++11, there are 3 parts to generate random numbers:

1. `std::random_device` uses an implementation defined source of entropy to seed an engine
2. The engine itself (such as `std::default_random_engine`) produces random values
3. The distribution, which consumes an engine value and produces a new value matching a certain distribution (uniform, bernoulli, poisson, ...)

*Note: both the engine and the distribution are (potentially) stateful and should be passed by reference.*

For example you could do:

```
std::vector<double> uniform(std::default_random_engine& engine, size_t length) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(0, 1);

    std::vector<double> result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != length; ++i) {
        result.push_back(dist(engine));
    }
    return result;
}
```

And invoke this function in `main`, which is tasked with seeding the engine:

```
int main()
{
    static size_t const Size = 10;

    // File to output results
    std::ofstream output("output.txt");

    // Initialize the engine
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine engine(rd());

    // Generate two sequences of uniform random variates
    std::vector<double> const u1 = uniform(engine, Size);
    std::vector<double> const u2 = uniform(engine, Size);

    // Output results
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        output << u1[i] << "\t" << u2[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks, that's what I get for not compiling :x